# Hooking a window with SetWinEventHook sometimes doesn't work

Tags: winapi, hook

I wrote some code to watch for window title changes. It works fine with different windows in my Windows 7. I use SetWinEventHook like that:

```
SetWinEventHook(EVENT_OBJECT_NAMECHANGE,
                EVENT_OBJECT_NAMECHANGE,
                0,
                WinEventCallback,
                processId,
                threadId,
                WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNTHREAD);
```

Callback:

```
void CALLBACK WinEventCallback(HWINEVENTHOOK hWinEventHook,
                           DWORD dwEvent,
                           HWND hwnd,
                           LONG idObject,
                           LONG idChild,
                           DWORD dwEventThread,
                           DWORD dwmsEventTime)
{
    qDebug("Window %p", hwnd);
    ...
    GetWindowText(hwnd, ...);
}
```

For one specific window I see the debug message "Window 0x0" all the time, e.g. I get the window handle set to zero in the callback. In this case GetWindowText fails. All other windows work fine. The question is why? I don't see anything extraordinary in Spy++:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Not all events generated may be associated with a window, especially for something as generic as a name change. The hook [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373885%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) specifically states that NULL windows are possible, so simply ignore them if your hook logic is window-oriented.  If you are seeing a window change its title but you are getting a NULL window in your callback, then either it is not a real window, or there was an issue marshaling the window to your callback, or something like that.

Comment: >it is not a real window

I can see it Spy++, this is regular WIn32 window with title, class and so on (see screenshot). This is very strange for me that I get NULLs.

Comment: That app is using WinForms, which handles UIs very differently than standard Win32 UIs. Maybe WinForms is not providing its HWND when dispatching the event, or maybe the hook dispatcher simply doesn't support WinForms. Do the other working windows also use WinForms?

Comment: _Do the other working windows also use WinForms?_

Yes, the other windows from the same application work fine. For that window I see that the message WM_SETTEXT fails (in Spy++ right click->Messages). This means that the window ignores WM_SETTEXT and sets the window title SOMEHOW in a different way.

Comment: Maybe the window is being custom-drawn.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes for the WinEventCallback's signature you are using.

Fix it by using this one: WinEventCallback(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint iEvent, IntPtr hWnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime)